# Fan running the battery dead on a 96 Acura

Tags: battery, acura, thermostat

Alright, my 1996 Acura 2.5TL is running the battery dead by running when not necessary. If it was continuously running after the engine shut off I would say stuck relay but it will both continue after the engine is off AND start long after the engine is cool (<= that one caught me by surprise). I suppose that means a bad thermostat but the compartment is so tight I cannot tell where the thermostat is.

Comment: Have you tried just changing the relay out with a known good one? If it's doing it cold, I'm thinking it's stuck.

Comment: I haven't swapped out the relay but the reason is is that sometimes it will start cold, without the engine running. I suppose if the relay was stuck it would make more sense what it was stuck open after being in a proper running state. This is opening without the engine even running or being warm.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to the game on this, but those fans are controlled by a radiator sensor and a fan timer unit. My first guess is that your radiator sensor (lower right side) is bad, but you would need to pull and test it.

Comment: Do you have any sites, pictures or diagrams that show the location of this sensor?

Comment: On your TL the sensor should be on the bottom radiator tank, probably on the passenger side @ the back of the radiator. It has a two pin connector I believe.